# Не передается переменная через include

Tags: ооп, php, переменные, функции

Здравствуйте!

Вот часть кода:

```
  if($_SESSION['status'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])
    {
      $test = 1312;
      open::view("form");
    }
```

Метод с класса

```
public function view($a)
{
  $patch = DOC_ROOT."/view/".$a."/index.php";
  include $patch;
}
```

Беда в том что когда я пытаюсь в этом файле вызвать переменную **$test**

То мне выдает что она не определенна. Пробивал так, тоже без успешно.

```
public function view($a,$b)
{ 
  $test = $b;
  $patch = DOC_ROOT."/view/".$a."/index.php";
  include $patch;
}
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: функция view должна быть статической public static function view

Comment: @mountpoint, переменная передастся только через второй метод

    public static function view($a)
    {
      $patch = DOC_ROOT."/view/".$a."/index.php";
      include $patch;
    }
    
    public static function view_p($a,$b) // этот
    {
    
      $test = $b;
      
      $patch = DOC_ROOT."/view/".$a."/index.php";
      include $patch;
    }
А как можно через первый?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проблема в области видимости, вы же подключаете файл внутри метода класса, у которого локальная область видимости

```
public function view($a, array $params = array())
{ 
  if (!empty($params)) {
      extract($params);
  }
  $patch = DOC_ROOT."/view/".$a."/index.php";
  include $patch;
}

$obj->view('view_name', array('test'=>$test));
```